# Current state END_ELEMENT is not among the statesCHARACTERS, COMMENT, CDATA, SPACE, ENTITY_REFERENCE, DTD valid for getText()

Tags: java, stax

I'm so new to java but I'm doing this project for school. I have a 4GB XML file (it's a wikipedia dump) need to parse. I use StAX and my code run succsefully for more than 400,000 lines (almost 50MB) but then I get this error.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Current
>   state END_ELEMENT is not among the statesCHARACTERS, COMMENT, CDATA,
>   SPACE, ENTITY_REFERENCE, DTD valid for getText()      at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLStreamReaderImpl.getText(XMLStreamReaderImpl.java:1081)
>     at tagremoving1.TagRemoving1.main(TagRemoving1.java:65)

I read somewhere when I use getText() I shoul check for null or empty elements so I did. Then it goes further but stops again with the same error. I looked up almost everywhere. I don't know what's wrong. 
This is my code:

```
XMLInputFactory factory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
     File file = new File("source.xml");
     FileInputStream fileReader = new FileInputStream(file);    
     factory.setProperty(XMLInputFactory.IS_COALESCING, true);
            factory.setProperty(XMLInputFactory.IS_REPLACING_ENTITY_REFERENCES,true);
            factory.setProperty(XMLInputFactory.IS_SUPPORTING_EXTERNAL_ENTITIES,false);
     PrintWriter writer1 = new PrintWriter("result.txt", "UTF-8");   

    XMLStreamReader reader = factory.createXMLStreamReader(fileReader);
    int counter = 1;
    while(reader.hasNext()){

        if(reader.next() == 1){ //If it is START_ELEMENT
            String name = reader.getLocalName();
            switch(name){
                case "page":
                    writer1.println("\r\npage" + counter + ":");  
                    counter++;
                    break;

                case "title":
                    reader.next();
                    if(reader != null && !"".equals(reader.toString())) 
                            writer1.println("Title: " + reader.getText());
                    break;

                case "text":
                    reader.next();
                    if(reader != null && !"".equals(reader.toString()))
                        writer1.println("Text: " + reader.getText());
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

    }
    writer1.flush();
    writer1.close();
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Could you maybe show us the XML around the point where the error happens?  Otherwise, all anyone can do is guess what's going on.

Comment: It stops in the middle of the topic (as i mentioned it's a wikipedia article) precisely in the middle of a "word" and the text is persian so I'm not sure if showing it is helpful. Is it possible that it's a memory problem? Because it's a big article. -@DawoodibnKareem

Comment: I really doubt whether it's a memory problem.  It's far more likely to be some kind of invalid XML, right in the middle of the document.  It would be really good if you can identify where in the document this happens, then take a look at the XML and see if you can see anything wrong.  To help you identify where it happens, you could try removing half of the document, then half of what remains, and so on, until you can find the problem happening in a manageable portion of the document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I figured it out!

I add another condition **reader.hasText()** to final 'if' and then everything was fine. Here is the code:

```
case "text":
    reader.next();
    if(reader != null && !"".equals(reader.toString()) && reader.hasText())                     
    writer1.println("Text: " + reader.getText());
    break;
```